# Problem on force components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

In this problem, is the direction of tension(725N) shown in the free body diagram correct?
Wouldn't such a direction lead to compression instead of tension.

Answer (score 2):

The diagram is correct. This is the force of the rope acting on the beam.

The force that the *rope* feels due to the beam pulling on it is equal in magnitude but in the opposite direction, as given by Newton’s third law.